# Why does polymorphism not work with overloaded methods in Java?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading

I have a basic understanding of how method overriding and overloading works in Java. But my question is why does the compiler searches for a most specific method based on the compile type of the argument? In other words, why does it searches based on the type of reference and not the type of object in case of method overloading?

Check the example below

```
class Base { }

class Derived extends Base { }

class Test {

    void foo(Base thing) { System.out.println("foo(Base)"); }
    void foo(Derived thing) { System.out.println("foo(Derived)"); }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Test tester = new Test(); 
        Base base = new Base(); 
        tester.foo(base);// 1st call 
        base = new Derived(); 
        tester.foo(base); // 2nd call
        tester.foo(new Derived()); // 3rd call
    } 
}
```

Actual Output

```
1st call: foo(Base)

2nd call: foo(Base)

3rd call: foo(Derived)
```

Output I was expecting

```
1st call: foo(Base)

2nd call: foo(Derived)

3rd call: foo(Derived)
```

Comment: Duplicate of [insert here]. Overloading is a compile time thing based on the static type of a variable, i.e. `Base base` in both #1 and #2.

Comment: What has methods to do with polymorphism in this case? The methods are simply printing what is passed in or specifically, what type of an object is passed in!

Answer (score 1):

1) Overloading happens at compile time i.e which method definition to 
execute is decided at compile time. 
2) You are assigning derived class object reference to base class 
object at run time.
3) So it is obviously not known at compile time which reference your 
base class object will have in future i.e at run time.
4) this is the reason why compiler looks at the type of reference in 
case of method overloading

Answer (score 0):

You must remember, when you define a variable type such as `Bass` the only values it can store are of itself and classes derived from itself such as `Derived`.

Once that variable has been assigned a variable type, it cannot be changed.

One way to think of it:

Say your `Bass` class has one field value that it stores:

```
class Bass {
String field1;

}
```

Say your `Derived` class stores an additional field"

```
class Derived extends Bass {
String field2;

}
```

Now say you create a bass instance:

```
Bass bass = new Base();
```

You can access the `field1` value from the object.

Now you say you do the following:

```
bass = new Derived();
```

You can still access the `field1` value from the object.
You cannot however access the `field2` value, since the bass instance does not store this value. It does not comply with its structure.

I hope this helps you understand why when setting a variable type equal to one of its derived classes it will not change the original variable type.